# To find the number of roots of the polynomial $z^{100} + 8z^{10} − 3z^3 + z^2 + z + 1$ inside the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am working my way through a problem set in complex analysis. I don't seem to work my way past this problem

Q) Let $f(z) = z^{100} + 8z^{10} − 3z^3 + z^2 + z + 1$. How many zeros (counting
multiplicities) does f have in the closed unit disc $|z|<1$?

What we can tell by looking at the coefficients is that the product of the roots is 1 and the sum of the roots is 0. From this I am tempted to think that it is a 50-50 split between roots inside the disc and roots outside. How do you do this?

Comment: The method you're expected to use and intended to practice, is applying Rouché's theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider $P(z)=z^{100}-3z^3+z^2+z+1$ then for $|z|=1$ $|P(z)|\leq 7$ and if $Q(z)=8z^{10}$ with $|Q(z)|=8$ for $|z|=1$ that is

$$ |P(z)|<|Q(z)|\quad\text{for}\quad |z|=1 $$
By Rouche's theorem $P+Q$ and $Q$ have same number of zeros in $|z|\leq 1.$

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this polynomial has 100 roots (counting multiplicities aswell).

There are many tools for estimating number of roots, a very elegant one is Rouche theorem:

Let $f,g \in Hol(U)$ and assume that $\gamma$ is a jordan curve (or a closed curve) in $U$ (meaning $int(\gamma) \subset U)$. We also assume that for any $z\in \gamma$ we have $|g(z)| <|f(z)|$.

Then the number of zeroes of $g+f$ inside $\gamma$ is the same as the number of zeroes of $f$

What do we do in this case? We split The polynomial to 2 polynomials, and we show the inequality.